# How to hang drywall on uneven horizontal plank wall

Tags: walls, old-house

I'm removing many layers of wall remodels in a 1913 house.  The last layer is 1x6 horizontal planks. They are not pretty like shiplap so I need to put up drywall. The three interior walls are pretty flat.  The exterior wall has some boards with parts that are lower than the rest.  I don't think shims will work.  Should I fill the low spots with plaster or drywall mud and then hang drywall?

Comment: Why do you think shims won't work?  How many boards are you talking about?

Comment: How wide are the low spots?  Drywall is usually placed on 2x4s or 2x6s at 16 to 24 inch spacing,  might just go right over low spots.

Comment: Are these planks meant to be a sheathing of some sort?

Comment: A couple of pictures - one wide shot showing a reasonable portion of the wall, and a closer shot with a tape measure showing the dimensions and depth of one of these low spots will help people understand what's going on. You can [edit] them right into your post.

Comment: Either fur it or finish the demo.